# I find that my V12/S2 is slower (~20%) than my V11/S2 instance, thoughts as to why?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am using JMeter to run stress tests against my MVC3(WebApp), EF6.1, SQL Azure(S2) application.

The V11 and V12 instance are identical. Basically I used the same "bacpac" file. When creating the V12 instance I created the new SQL Server, and then imported the "bacpac" , choosing the S2 pricing tier. So both instance are the same apart from one is on a V11 server and the other is on a V12 server.

My JMeter Test case has about 60 calls in it. Initially I run with one loop and then with five loops, and with differing numbers of concurrent users as follows:

```
1 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V11/S2  550ms (average)
1 User, 30 sec rampup, 5 loop   V11/S2  555ms (average)
1 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V12/S2  755ms (average)
1 User, 30 sec rampup, 5 loop   V12/S2  800ms (average)

5 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V11/S2  620ms (average)
5 User, 30 sec rampup, 5 loop   V11/S2  684ms (average)
5 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V12/S2  800ms (average)
5 User, 30 sec rampup, 5 loop   V12/S2  972ms (average)

10 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V11/S2  868ms (average)
10 User, 30 sec rampup, 5 loop   V11/S2  1317ms (average)
10 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V12/S2  1000ms (average)
10 User, 30 sec rampup, 5 loop   V12/S2  1686ms (average)

20 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V11/S2  2422ms (average)
20 User, 30 sec rampup, 1 loop   V12/S2  3000ms (average)
```

The above test case has a mix of creates, updates and selects. Also the times represent the complete time for the request.  However, from looking at my NewRelic graphs I can see that the .NET component is minor and consistent, whereas the SQL server component is the major and variable one ie that is the one that shoots up when the user number increases.

I have seen write-ups that one should get 25% speed ups. With the above results It seems I will migrate from "Web Edition" to V11, but not to V12. I would be interested if others have experienced the same or whether you could offer a reason or possible solution, excepting use of S3 or P1....

**Edit**

I have done further testing with all of the compatibility levels ie 100,110 and 120, using the same test plan as above ie about 60 http calls. My original database was developed on SQL 2008, and was set at Compatibility Level 100. However there was neglible difference between compatibility levels on V12, and all performed poorly as against V11. Ie:

```
S2/V11/100 10 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  632ms (Av. Req.duration)
S2/V12/120 10 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  1029ms 
S2/V12/110 10 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  1111ms
S2/V12/100 10 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  1088ms
S2/V11/100 20 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  1180ms 
S2/V12/120 20 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  4190ms 
S2/V12/110 20 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  4388ms
S2/V12/100 20 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  4269ms
S2/V11/100 30 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  2745ms 
S2/V12/120 30 users, rampup 300 secs, 3 loops  7937ms
```

So it seems I can get an extra 10 users to operate concurrently on S2/V11 on my DB than on S2/V12 which is significant. So at present it seems that I am best to stay with V11 until I need S3. my only thought as to the cause is that the DB was developed using SQL 2008. Also I use Entity Framework 6, perhaps I need to tweak the configuration? I believe not, never had to before.

Comment: Is it the same instance the of the WebApp? You might be seeing impact of a noisy neighbour or similar. You might be on a busier SQL Server V12 node than V11 node.  Have you run through the performance tuning processes guidance? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn369873.aspx

Comment: Azure DB provides performance guarantees for non web and business tiers and shouldn't have noisy neighbors in theory. Can you look at the sys.resource_stats view to compare the resource usage on V11 vs V12.

Comment: Thanks for the comments above. Will check out the sys.resource_stats view. Also will rerun some of the tests on a fresh V12 instance today to see if any difference is noticed

Comment: I notice that "sys.resource_stats" takes about 30 minutes to provide the data which then contains the 5 minute slots of analysis.

Comment: For sys.resource_stats, we are working on getting that sped up currently. As a work around try sys.dm_db_resource_stats against the database directly, it will give you 15 second averages instead of 5 minutes and is quite a bit faster.

Also an important distinction between V11 and V12 is one uses SQL 2012 and the other SQL 2014, 2014 has a different query optimizer that can change query execution, if you are getting different query plans try changing the compatibility level.

Comment: @cbattlegear , Think I nearly missed an important aspect to your comment. What you seem to be inferring is that queries that run well against V11 may not be optimised for V12, and therefore run more slowly. Am I correct? How do I resolve this? Change the compatibility level where? I assume this will downgrade to V11 compatibility? Longer term should profile and optimise against V12 compatibility or what?

Comment: Just found "ALTER DATABASE Test SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;"

Comment: Added new measurements in "Edit" to question, taking into account the compatibility levels. No benefit found.

Comment: Sam, I'd be happy to help. There are a number of resources that you can use to dive deeper into benchmarking Azure SQL DB including some 3rd party results that end up with a different conclusion than you've reached here.  Specifically at MSFT we use and describe an Azure SQL Database Benchmark for measuring throughput - details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741327.aspx and the 3rd party - details here https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/12/17/azure-sql-database-v12-performance-tests-show-significant-performance-increase/

Comment: Your also welcome to reach out to me directly guyhay @ microsoft.com